# Multi-select List in SwiftUI+Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to load in a list of collections from Firestore and have them be individually selectable. I have it set up where it's pulling in the list from Firestore, but if I select one, it selects all. Also, how would I pull this array into a VStack of buttons instead of a List? In my selection screen, this list is sort of in the middle of the page, and I'd rather do it with buttons than a List, as the List component isn't dynamic in size.

Thanks for the help, code below!

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirestoreTest: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TriggersViewModel()
    @State private var isSelected = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(viewModel.triggers) { trigger in
            Button(action: { self.isSelected.toggle() }) {
                HStack {
                    if self.isSelected {
                    Text(trigger.name)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))

                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemPink))
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                    } else {
                        Text(trigger.name)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                            .font(.system(size: 16))
                    }
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchData()
        }
        
    }
}
```

TriggerViewModel.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

class TriggersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var triggers = [Trigger]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("triggers").order(by: "name").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Documents")
                return
            }
            
                self.triggers = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Trigger in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Trigger(name: name)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Trigger: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: This is the issue `self.isSelected.toggle()` as isSelected is a property of the view. So if it's set to true, it's set to true for everything `if self.isSelected`. Don't you want to just set it for true for the trigger(s) that was selected? If so, you need to add a property to the trigger to determine that OR, add a property to the view to keep try of which triggers(s) are selected - e.g. `var selectedTriggers = [Trigger]` so if you select trigger 1, 3 and 7, you can keep track of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `isSelected` into model and use `ForEach` for `VStack`.

Here is possible solution:

```
struct Trigger: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var isSelected = false
}
```

now you can remove `@State private var isSelected = false`, and

```
VStack {
    ForEach(viewModel.triggers.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        Button(action: { viewModel.triggers[i].isSelected.toggle() }) {
            HStack {
                if viewModel.triggers[i].isSelected {
                Text(viewModel.triggers[i].name)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))

                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemPink))
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                } else {
                    Text(viewModel.triggers[i].name)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This all makes total sense, but when I put in the code as written, I get a blank page, it doesn't seem to be pulling any of the items from the db

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, thanks so much!!